# Kendo Date Picker selection by class name with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How do i get the value of a Kendo Date Picker by class name.   The reason being is because im using the name and id attributes for something else.   As you can see below the class attribute is dynamic.  Every other time ive selected a Kendo Date Picker, i've always used the ID attribute.    Is it possible to select by class attribute?

```
 @Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
              .Name("SurveyResponse.DateRes[" + @guid + "].Date")
              .Format("MM/dd/yyyy")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { 
                       onkeydown = "javascript:return false;", 
                       onblur = "ConditionalTextBox(" + @item.SurveyQuestionID + ",'datecontrol')", 
                       @placeholder = "Your answer", 
                       @required = "required", 
                       @class = "IsConditionalTextBox_" + @item.SurveyQuestionID 
                       })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have knocked up a quick dojo for you showing how you can access the value/control using the id, class and data attribute

http://dojo.telerik.com/udIfO

if you want to use the data attribute method (my preferred) then just add it to your htmlAttributes using `@data_My_Attribute` this translates to `data-My-Attribute`

but just for completeness here is the sample for you to view:

```
        <h4>Show e-mails from:</h4>
        <input id="datepicker" value="10/10/2011" style="width: 100%" class="dateClass" data-my-attribute="date" />

        <h4 style="margin-top: 2em;">Add to archive mail from:</h4>
        <input id="monthpicker" value="November 2011" style="width: 100%" class="monthClass" data-my-attribute="month" />
      <button class="k-button k-primary" type="button">See results</button>
      <br/>
      <div>
     <br/>
      <div id="results">
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // create DatePicker from input HTML element
        $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();

        $("#monthpicker").kendoDatePicker({
            // defines the start view
            start: "year",

            // defines when the calendar should return date
            depth: "year",

            // display month and year in the input
            format: "MMMM yyyy"
        });

      $('button.k-button').on('click', function(){
        var model = ''; 
         model = model +  'From <strong>#datepicker</strong> using id as selector::' + $("#datepicker").data('kendoDatePicker').value();
         model += '<br/>From <strong>#monthpicker</strong> using id as selector::' + $("#monthpicker").data('kendoDatePicker').value();
         model = model +  '<br/>From <strong>#datepicker</strong> using input.dateClass as selector::' + $("input.dateClass").data('kendoDatePicker').value();
         model += '<br/>From <strong>#monthpicker</strong> using input.monthClass as selector::' + $("input.monthClass").data('kendoDatePicker').value();
         model = model +  '<br/>From <strong>#datepicker</strong> using input[data-my-attribute="date"] as selector::' + $("input[data-my-attribute='date']").data('kendoDatePicker').value();
         model += '<br/>From <strong>#monthpicker</strong> using input[data-my-attribute="month"] as selector::' + $("input[data-my-attribute='month']").data('kendoDatePicker').value();
        $('#results').empty().html(model);
      }); 

    });
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm.  And using data attributes gives me an even better idea of how to do what i need to do.    But you's answered the original question.  Mucho thanks

Comment: Glad it helped.